# How can I create dynamic table with vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Hi I want to create dynamic vue table 100*100, but td keep shows me the error 
that it is invalid v-for..
how can I create 100*100 table via for loop??

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr v-for="(row, i) in this.rows" v-bind:key="i">
        <td v-for="(col,k)in this.cols" v-bind:key="k">
          {{ col[k] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Table",
  data(){
return{
rows:100,
cols:100
}
}

};
</script>

<style scoped>
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Usatei has pointed out, change:

```
   <tr v-for="(row, i) in this.rows" v-bind:key="i">
    <td v-for="(col,k)in this.cols" v-bind:key="k">
```

to:

```
   <tr v-for="(row, i) in rows" v-bind:key="i">
    <td v-for="(col,k)in cols" v-bind:key="k">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove the this from your html component, it should be ok.